# Does Titanium have method for "didReceiveRemoteNotification" of Objective-C?

Tags: notifications, titanium, push

I would like to receive remote push notification when the app is on the foreground. I think I can use "didReceiveRemoteNotification" in Objective-C, but how about in Titanium? I've been searching solutions but can't find anything. Does anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i was wrong last time. It's very hard to find but Titanium supports a way of interacting with PushNotifications.
Please take a look at [`Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications`](http://urbanairship.com). It provides a callback that is executed when you receive a Push Notification.

The other posted solutions below may provide a better integration for titanium so it's up to you what you want to use. But this should answer your original question.

> Unfortunately Titanium only supports local notifications on iOS. If
>   you want to support remote notifications you can use
>
> - [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com)
> - [ACS (Appcelerator Cloud Services)](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/07/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html) or
> - you write your own module that provides "didReceiveRemoteNotifcation" as an app event to your app
>
> As far as i know you can only listen on [local notifications](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-event-notification) by
>   default but you can try [this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-event-notification) method if it reacts on remote
>   notifications..

Comment: Thanks mr.VVoo! I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium currently only supports local notifications (by default) I believe. You might want to take a look at [AppCelerator](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/appcelerator-titanium-push-notification/) as a solution.